# ng-controller cannot define on laravel blade

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using laravel 5.4 and angular JS 1.6.2 to create a new webpage.
But the ng-controller was not working on Laravel.
Following are my codes:

PHP (data.blade.php):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Your Profile')

@section('sidebar')
@parent

@stop


@section('content')



<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="my">
@{{name}}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("my", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.name = "EEE" ;        
});
</script>

@endsection
```

I got following error message in chrome:

```
angular.min.js:122Error:             
[$controller:ctrlreg]http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=my
at angular.min.js:6
at angular.min.js:92
at ca (angular.min.js:75)
at n (angular.min.js:67)
at g (angular.min.js:60)
at g (angular.min.js:61)
at g (angular.min.js:61)
at g (angular.min.js:61)
at g (angular.min.js:61)
at angular.min.js:60
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5RhS.png)

Comment: have you tried to move the script to the front of you div?

Comment: @Pengyy this should not matter.

Comment: the error message shows that the controller my is not defined.

Comment: @Pengyy we already know what the question is. =)

Comment: @lin ok, maybe you should answer yourself to help others.

Comment: This looks fine from here. Have you tried to clean your browser cache?

Comment: @Pengyy Hi Pengyy, thanks for your comment. Yes, I tried everything your said.  If the page was not in section part of Laravel, it works well. I was confusing whether Laravel block the ng-controller tag.

Comment: @lin Hi lin. Yes, I tried to clean the cache, but it still not working. I think it is because the ng-controller div in Laravel section part that makes javascript failing to define ng-controller